# How to show a php radio input value on a php email?

Tags: php, forms, email, input, radio-button

I have a php form with 4 radio inputs as below:

```
<?php if( $chauffeur_data['enable-paypal'] == '1' ) { ?>
            <div class="radio-wrapper clearfix"><input type="radio" name="payment-method" value="paypal" <?php if( $paypal_check == '1' ) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> /><label><?php esc_html_e('Pay with PayPal','chauffeur'); ?></label><img src="<?php echo plugins_url('../../assets/images/paypal.png', __FILE__); ?>"></div>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if( $chauffeur_data['enable-stripe'] == '1' ) { ?>
            <div class="radio-wrapper clearfix"><input type="radio" name="payment-method" value="stripe" <?php if( $stripe_check == '1' ) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> /><label><?php esc_html_e('Pay with Credit Card','chauffeur'); ?></label><img src="<?php echo plugins_url('../../assets/images/stripe.png', __FILE__); ?>"></div>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if( $chauffeur_data['enable-cash'] == '1' ) { ?>
            <div class="radio-wrapper clearfix"><input type="radio" name="payment-method" value="cash" <?php if( $cash_check == '1' ) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> /><label><?php esc_html_e('Pay with Cash to the Driver','chauffeur'); ?></label></div>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if( $chauffeur_data['enable-pos'] == '1' ) { ?>
            <div class="radio-wrapper clearfix"><input type="radio" name="payment-method" value="pos" <?php if( $pos_check == '1' ) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> /><label><?php esc_html_e('Pay with Card on POS in the Car','chauffeur'); ?></label></div>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php // If all payment gateways are disabled 
        if( $chauffeur_data['enable-paypal'] != '1' && $chauffeur_data['enable-stripe'] != '1' && $chauffeur_data['enable-cash'] != '1' &&
        $chauffeur_data['enable-pos'] != '1' ) { ?> 
            <input type="hidden" name="payment-method" value="cash" />
        <?php } ?>

        <button name="pay_now" id="pay_now" class="payment-button" type="submit">
            <?php esc_html_e('Proceed To Payment','chauffeur'); ?>
        </button>

        <?php } else { ?>

            <input type="hidden" name="payment-method" value="cash" />

            <button name="pay_now" id="pay_now" class="payment-button" type="submit">
                <?php esc_html_e('Proceed To Book','chauffeur'); ?>
            </button>

        <?php } ?>
```

When one of the radio buttons is checked, how can I show its value (e.g. pos) to the email I send?

The email is like below. What should be my code to show the radio button choice?

```
$customer_email_content .= '<li><strong>' . esc_html__('Payment Method you Selected','chauffeur') . ': </strong>' . '**payment-method-goes-here**' . '</li>'."\r\n";
```

Comment: It'll be in the `$_POST` array when you submit the form. Look for `$_POST['pos']`

Comment: $_POST['payment-method']

Comment: Question edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After form is submitted, get the radio button value from $_POST array;

```
$payment_method = $_POST['payment-method'];
```

Use $payment_method to show the value of the radio button that is selected.

```
$customer_email_content .= '<li><strong>' . esc_html__('Payment Method you Selected','chauffeur') . ': </strong>' . $payment_method . '</li>'."\r\n";
```

Comment: I did it. Thank you very much for your help!